# Como adicionar novas colunas no h:datatable no jsf sem dar refresh que o update faz na tabela,

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Gente, estou com um problema, criei uma consulta paginada que traz sempre 5 registros, implementei com jquery um **$(window).scroll** para que sempre que o scroll chegue no final da página ele traga mais 5 registros e atualize a tabela usando **update="table"**. O meu problema é que o update ele da um refresh na tabela e recria tudo de novo, e isso causa um pequeno delay quando tem muitos registros, gostaria de saber se é possivel colocar os 5 novos registros na tabela sem dar o refresh nba tabela toda que o update faz.

Comment: acho que se você utilizasse o angularJS ajudaria e muito

Comment: Cara, insira o seu código na pergunta, mas acho que não vai rolar fazer isso. Concordo com o @MarcosHenrique, seria mais fácil com angular.